# discord.py mute role permission adding

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So i made mute command for discord bot. it works, but doesn't add any permissions to 'Muted' role? Any ideas what's wrong?
Code:

```
@client.command(name = 'mute')
@commands.has_permissions(manage_permissions = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    muted = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = 'muted')
    perms = discord.Permissions(send_messages = False)
    if muted not in ctx.guild.roles:
        muted = await ctx.guild.create_role(name = 'muted', permissions = perms)
    memroles = discord.utils.get(member.roles)
    if muted in memroles:
        await ctx.send(f':x: This person is already muted')
    await member.add_roles(muted)
    await ctx.send(f':white_check_mark: **User <@{member.id}> was muted!**')
    print(f'User {member} was muted!')
```

Error:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\endport_semegen\discordpy\smth.py", line 62, in mute
    if muted in memroles:
TypeError: argument of type 'Role' is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: argument of type 'Role' is not iterable```
````

Comment: Try by adding `.name` after `memroles` is it work? @enderport

Comment: nope, still doesn't work, but error is different

Comment: Error is `File "D:\endport_semegen\discordpy\smth.py", line 62, in mute
    if muted in memroles.name:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Role`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when you `discord.utils.get` on the member roles.

[From the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get), emphasis mine:

> A helper that ***returns the first element*** in the iterable that ***meets all the traits*** passed in attrs. This is an alternative for find().

Since you didn't provide anything for it to check, it will return the *first* role that satisfies the requirements - the first role the member has. Obviously, this is not the list of roles that you wanted.

The solution is to simply remove the `get`. There's no reason to do it. Now, `member.roles` will be a list that you can do checking with.

```py
    memroles = member.roles
    if muted in memroles:
        await ctx.send(f':x: This person is already muted')
```